# Почему не компилируется Arrays.sort для массива из примитивов?

Tags: java, сортировка

Почему такой код не скомпилируется?

```java
int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Arrays.sort(b, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o2, o1));
```

Если я меняю тип массива на `Integer[]`, то все работает:

```java
Integer[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Arrays.sort(b, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o2, o1));
```

Comment: Потому что количество закрывающих скобок не равно количеству открывающих.

Comment: @Igor, это опечатка, идея выдает такую ошибку 'compare(int, int)' in 'java.lang.Integer' cannot be applied to '(T, T)'

Comment: Ничего не знаю, это правильный ответ на вопрос.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(int[])` не принимает на вход компаратор. Хотите с компаратором, сделайте копию `int[] -> Integer[]` и сортируйте её. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699141/how-to-sort-an-array-of-ints-using-a-custom-comparator

Comment: Int это примитив, а Integer это объект, компаратор работает с объектом, для того чтобы использовать примитив нужно воспользоваться классом оберткой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics в Java устроены таким образом, что они не работают с примитивными типами, а только с объектами. Например, нельзя написать `List<int>`, но можно `List<Integer>`.

Таким образом, если внимательно посмотреть на сигнатуры методов `Arrays.sort()`, то увидим, что есть такие методы:

```java
void sort(Object[] a)
```

```java
void sort(int[] a)
```

```java
<T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Но нет такого:

```java
void sort(int[] a, Comparator<Integer> c)
```

Значит, единственный способ отсортировать массив с помощью `Arrays.sort()` с использованием компаратора — скопировать `int[]` в `Integer[]`:

```java
int[] primitives = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Integer[] objects = new Integer[primitives.length];
Arrays.setAll(objects, i -> primitives[i]);
Arrays.sort(objects, (o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o2, o1));
```

Answer (score -1):

Потому что компаратор не знает какой тип у a  и b

```
Integer.compare((int)o2, (int)o1))
```

Хотя оно будет работать из без компаратора

Comment: Пробовал так, выдает ошибку 'sort(T[], java.util.Comparator<? super T>)' in 'java.util.Arrays' cannot be applied to '(int[], <lambda expression>)'